# Solr: How to to search special character with priority

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I am new to Solr and using it through SolrNet. When i send a search query for c#, it matches 'C,C++' as well.

How can I give the more priority to the results which have exact match 'C#' ? 
Or please suggest a better solution to handle such special cases in Solr query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things you need to take care of

1. ensure you escape special chars like +, -, , *
2. ensure you store them in a field that don't have analyzers removing these chars
3. put a higher field boost for the field used to store these chars as opposed to fully analyzed free text field.

Comment: What was the answer here? I am having the same issue, but I don't see why this is an accepted answer as it is not an actual solution.